# How do we work with OS-independent paths in Perl 6?

Tags: windows, raku

Perl 6 does have classes that include [common OSs](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::Path::Win32) for specifying paths, as well as [`$*SPEC`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#index-entry-$*SPEC) which contains the file specification. [New paths](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::Path#method_new) use by default current value of SPEC. However, it's not clear at all, from the documentation, if doing something like

```
mkdir IO::Path.new( 'a/b/c' );
```

is going to work correctly across all operating systems, or you need to specifically create OS-dependent code. Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm trying this on Windows 7 (one of the OSes you seem to be mostly interested in according to tags), using

```
This is Rakudo Star version 2019.03.1 built on MoarVM version 2019.03
implementing Perl 6.d.
```

And it seems to work just like that

```
> with mkdir IO::Path.new('a/b/c') { say .e; say .absolute }
True
C:\rakudo\a\b\c
```

The directory is indeed created properly.

Note that `IO::Path` takes an `IO::Spec` object defaulting to `$*SPEC` in its constructor, so the necessary OS-dependent part is available to the object. In Rakudo the `IO::Spec` is indeed used by [mkdir](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/17d036ad45b6be866614ddd6dc907738aa967b16/src/core.c/IO/Path.pm6#L512) through [.absolute](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/17d036ad45b6be866614ddd6dc907738aa967b16/src/core.c/IO/Path.pm6#L220).
There also is a [roast test](https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/d19f6ae8d6fb5ebf96291fb0dd7fb4ba91d1bf95/S32-io/io-path.t#L42) about `/` in an `IO::Path` becoming `\` on Windows.

As Elizabeth Mattijsen pointed out, Windows seems to just support forward slashes by itself. Others claim that this has been the case [forever](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/23123-when-did-windows-start-accepting-forward-slash-path-separator#post85372):

> Actually, every version of Windows, and every version of MS-DOS from 2.0 on, has accepted "/" as a path delimiter.

Comment: Isn't that because Windows 7 and higher support forward slashes also out of the box?

Answer (score 4):

On a Windows 10 Enterprise VM:

```
C:\Users\me>c:/rakudo/bin/perl6 -e "mkdir IO::Path.new( 'a/b/c' )"

C:\Users\me>tree a
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is xxx
C:\USERS\ME\A
└───b
    └───c
```